# Javascript Returning a Type Error "Unable to get property '1' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: javascript

I can't for the life of me find out exactly what this error means in relation to my code.

HTML

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles.css" type="text/css">
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="#0033CC" vlink="#0033CC" alink="#0033CC">
<p><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b><font color="#000000">Job ref:</font></b><font color="#000000">12345 <br>
<b>Position:</b> Position Title <br>
<b>Organisation:</b> Organisation Name <br>
<b>Location: </b> UK, England, London <br>
<b>Closing date:</b> 24/09/2015<br>
<b>Job Type:</b> Permanent <br>
<b>Salary:</b> £100,000 per annum </font></font></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><font color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Details:</b></font></p>
<p><font color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">This is a description</font></p>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  DataExtractor.AddHeader(1, 'Country');

  var tmp = document.body.outerHTML.match(/Location: <\/b> ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+)/i);

  var country = tmp[1] 

  if (country) {
  for (var i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {

  DataExtractor.StartNewResult();
  DataExtractor.AddResult(1, country[i]);
   }
   }
```

When run it gives me the error as in the title.  Can anyone shed any light on what i'm missing?

Thank you

Comment: Quite clearly `country` is not what you think it is. Log it out before the loop and you'll be able to solve it.

Comment: `document.body.outerHTML.match` — this is a really weird way to do things, use DOM to get text data from HTML.

Comment: I'd rather say `tmp` is `null`.

Comment: I hope that HTML is proprietary and not something you wrote...

Comment: insert the line "console.log(tmp);" after the var tmp line and see what is in tmp by looking from a browser in the Javascript console (look through the browser menus for "developer tools", "error console" that sort of thing).   Chances are tmp is not an array or tmp[1] does not exist.

Comment: I tried the code [here in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vry8y/) and found that `tmp` is indeed an array, and `country` is the string `"UK"` _for that particular html_ - but you need to add a test to your code to be sure `tmp` is an array because for other html content the regex might not match. I don't know why you'd loop through the letters of the country. It's also possible that the problem is in one of the `DataExtractor` methods that you don't show.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked if tmp is an array? Try the following piece:

```
var country
if( tmp ){
country = tmp[1]
}else{
alert('tmp is not set')
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer but a debugging step.

Comment: While this copes with the error, it does not really provide a solution for the problem/task.

Comment: Okay thanks for that, I got the alert.  Next question is how does one go about setting tmp?

Comment: @Tom - the `tmp` variable will be `null` if the regex used by `.match()` doesn't actually match anything within your html content. You can test that with `if(tmp)` as suggested, but if there is no match the next step is up to you: it really depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @nnnnnn Sorry, bit confused, the code does actually match the html content as can be seen in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsp003/3qudW/2/), but when implimented it throws up the error.  The intention is  to break up the location line by its commas into country, city and state.  This is all a bit new to me so apologies if i seem a bit slow :)

Comment: @Tom - Yes, the regex matches _that_ content, but what is the content when implemented in your real site? Does the html for the page where the error occurs have exactly the same number of spaces (including the one between `:` and `</b>`)?

Comment: @Tom [Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/502381). Especially in this case: you can't be 100% sure that the browser's representation of the DOM matches the regex pattern. You need to read up on selecting individual DOM elements. If there's any way you can modify the HTML structure it becomes trivial if you can wrap the text you want in a span for example (and you can fix that markup from 1995 at the same time).

Comment: @Juhana Thanks am aware of the reasons not to use RegEx for parsing, but my hands are tied with this one. I have to use my works in-house dataextractor for collating my company data and I don't have access to modify the html. All the searching i have done to answer this question means that I am more than aware that many of you think it's a bad idea! :)

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you it appears that the spaces on the line are inconsistent, I assumed they would be the same on every page of documentation. So I now need to work on changing my expression to allow for this.  I thank you for helping me work this one out, but I sure feel dumb!

Comment: Actually, on reflection im even more confused.  Taking the example in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsp003/3qudW/2/), if the spaces in the html match the tmp variable then there is no reason it shouldn't find a match...or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believed your tmp variable is null as your regular expression fail to match any.

Also you should include 'g' in your regular expression parameter, means like / /ig. Bcoz you are expecting more than one match. Also use defensive programmin by checking length is really equal or more than two etc.

Comment: I don't think the OP needs the `g` flag - the expectation is that the pattern will match one string, but the sub-matches will make up the array elements.

Comment: Without 'g' parameter it will exit from the first match returning an array of single element.